# ListBox Binding with Global Index

Tags: wpf, binding, listbox

My application has a couple of ObservableCollections, one which is nested within an element of the other. Each contain a number of fields e.g.

ObservableCollectionA (called Listings)

- Title
- Description
- Address
- Images As MediaItems

ObservableCollectionB (called MediaItems)

- ImageName
- Src
- DisplayTime

Currently I have been accessing ObservableCollections as follows:

`Listings(0).MediaItems(0).ImageName`

My application has the main Window display the items from Listings and a UserControl which contains a ListBox which displays the items from MediaItems.

Currently my Window is bound to Listings using code in the New method:

```
Dim AppLocal As Program = Application.CurrentItem
AppLocal.CurrentItem = 0
Me.DataContext = Listings.Item(AppLocal.CurrentItem)
```

For the Listings ObservableCollection, the UserControl has a XAML DataContext which references a local method which pulls the records from the nested MediaItems ObservableCollection.

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <ObjectDataProvider ObjectType="{x:Type local:ThumbImageLoader}" MethodName="LoadImagesv2" IsAsynchronous="True"  />
</UserControl.DataContext>
<Grid x:Name="ThumbListBoxGrid">
    <ListBox x:Name="ThumbListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" />
</Grid>
```

The method is here:

```
Public NotInheritable Class ThumbImageLoader
Public Shared Function LoadImagesv2() As List(Of MediaItems)

    Dim AppLocal As Program = Application.Current

    Dim ThumbImages As New List(Of MediaItems)

    ThumbImages = Listings(AppLocal.CurrentItem).MediaItems

    Return ThumbImages
End Function
End Class
```

Whilst developing the UI layout I have just been binding the first item (0 index). I now want to be able to set AppLocal.CurrentItem from anywhere in the application so the Window and the ListBox are updated.

Ideally I would like it so when the global property index changes, the UI is updated.

How do I do this?

Is there a better way to go about it?

Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I discovered the joy of CollectionView. Offered exactly what I was after and was excrutiatingly easy to implement. I was blown away at not only how easy it was to implement, but I managed to cut out more lines of code than I used to implement it.

I implemented a public  CollectionViewSource

```
Public ListingDataView As CollectionViewSource
```

In my main Window, I implemeted it as follows:

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="ListingDataView" />
```

and bound my top-level Grid to it:

```
<Grid DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource ListingDataView}}">
```

In my Application Startup I set the CollectionView Source

```
AppLocal.ListingDataView = CType(Application.Current.MainWindow.Resources("ListingDataView"), CollectionViewSource)
AppLocal.ListingDataView.Source = Listings
```

The next part which impressed me the most was implementing it for my User Control. I remembered the UserControl is inheriting from the main window so it has access to the CollectionView already, so I ditched the separate Class and Method binding in favour for this:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MediaItems}" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" />
```

Now whene I want to set the Current List Index, I simply call this:

```
AppLocal.ListingDataView.View.MoveCurrentToPosition(AppLocal.CurrentProperty)
```

A few milliseconds later, the UI updates automatically.

Done!!

Answer (score 0):

When you want multiple source data (like your observable collection properties and the index for the observable collection) to a single target you should use `MultiBinding`.

So in your case somethign like this should help...

```
<ListBox x:Name="ThumbListBox" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" >
   <ListBox.ItemsSource>
      <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource CollectionAndIndexCollaborator}">
           <Binding Path="Listings" />
           <Binding Path="Application.CurrentItem.CurrentItem" />
      </MultiBinding> 
   </ListBox.ItemsSource>
</ListBox>
```

provided that ....

1. Your data context is some class that holds the `Application` object via a property of same name `Application` and the `Listings` collection via property of same name `Listings`.
2. Your DataContext class and `Application` class must have `INotifyPropertyChanged` implemented. It should also raise notifications for `Application` and Setter of `CurrentItem` and `CurrentItem.CurrentItem` properties.
3. `CollectionAndIndexCollaborator.Convert()` method returns the same indexed value as the final collection....

   return ((ObservableCollection)values[0]).Item(int.Parse(values[1])) ;

where assuming `MyListingType` is the `T` of your `Listings` collection.

This way when **anyone** changes the global `Application.CurrentItem.CurrentItem` the multi binding above will get notified and will select the required `Listings` item.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion AngelWPF - I ended up going with something slightly different. I'll post the results shortly.